# Kubernetes job never ends

Tags: kubernetes

I have a k8 job to publish a sql-server dacpac using the `sqlpackage` tool. The job works, the db is successfully deployed, but the job is stuck in the Running status.

How can I ensure the job ends once the `sqlpackage` has finished running?

---

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-publish-job
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-publish-job
        namespace: my-namespace
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-db-publish
          image: my-db-image:v1.0.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command:
                - /bin/bash
                - -c
                - >
                    /sqlpackage/sqlpackage \
                      /Action:Publish \
                      /SourceFile:"/my-db.dacpac"  \
                      /p:DropObjectsNotInSource=True \
                      /p:DoNotDropObjectTypes="Users;Permissions;RoleMembership;ServerRoleMembership" \
                      /p:IgnoreAuthorizer=True \
                      /p:IgnorePermissions=True \
                      /TargetUser:sa \
                      /TargetPassword:my_db_password \
                      /TargetDatabaseName:MyDb \
                      /TargetServerName:my.db.server
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Could you please provide job logs and result of `kubectl describe jobs/my-publish-job`?

Answer (score 0):

When defining a Job in Kubernetes you can set the property `activeDeadlineSeconds`.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: your-job
spec:
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 100
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - [...]
```

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/